# Haskell Persistent Joins with Esqueleto

Tags: sql, haskell

I've been looking into the Persistent library to interface with sql databases. Suppose I have a database containing recipes, with Recipe, Ingredient, and RecIng tables.

My (admittedly limited) understanding of persistent leads me to believe I should define the tables like this:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Recipe 
    title String
Ingredient 
    name String
RecIng
    recId RecipeId
    ingId IngredientId
    quantity Int
|]
```

With this, it is possible to use Esqueleto to get the inner join between these tables:

```
select $
from $ \(i `InnerJoin ` ri `InnerJoin` r) -> do
    on (r ^. RecipeId ==. ri ^. RecIngIngId)
    on (i ^. IngredientId ==. ri ^. RegIngRecId)
    return (r, ri, i)
```

This returns  tuple of (Recipe, RecIng, Ingredient).

What I really want is a way to query recipes that results in the following:

```
data Recipe = Recipe { title :: String
                     , ingredients :: [Ingredient]
                     }

data Ingredient = Ingredient { name :: String
                             , quantity :: Integer
                             }
```

Other than defining an additional set of data types, and converting the tuples, is there a best practice for doing this kind of thing?

Comment: As far as I know you need to map between the persistent representation and the custom data type manually. It's a bit of boiler plate but in this case I kind of like it, you get a clear mapping to what's in the DB, and converting from that to another type is very type safe :-) There may also be cases where you don't want to fetch the data with joins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

+1 to Adam's comment, it's the right answer IMO.

A separate approach you *could* take would be to use embedded entities, which would essentially mean JSON-encoding the list of ingredients into each recipe. But this would be bad SQL design, would cause table locking issues for updates, and wouldn't scale well for large numbers of ingredients.

In other words, there's a mismatch between the Haskell representation you want to work with and the right way to store the data in the database. This doesn't mean there's a problem with either your database format or your Haskell datatypes: it's a logical difference. The right response to this gap is to have two datatypes and an intelligent way to convert between them.

Comment: Do you have an opinion on whether this would be better achieved by getting everything in one query via esqueleto joins (which presumably would use one database transaction, but might take up a lot of memory), or using standard persistent to get specific results?

Comment: Either approach can be done with a single database transaction. If you go without the join, you'll avoid the overhead of transferring the recipe information for each ingredient. But using the join avoids extra database roundtrips, and for multiple recipes is likely even more of a performance win. If you're talking raw performance, the only real answer I can give you is to implement both and benchmark. If you're looking for better style: choose the one that you can understand better.