# Simplifying Persistent & Esqueleto code

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

I have a fairly simple query that does two outer joins.  (A meal has many recipes which in turn have many foods).

```
getMeals :: (MonadIO m) => Key DbUser -> SqlPersistT m [Meal]
getMeals user =
  fmap deserializeDb $ E.select $
        E.from $ \(m `E.InnerJoin` u `E.LeftOuterJoin` r `E.LeftOuterJoin` f) -> do
          E.on     (r ?. DbRecipeId E.==. f ?. DbFoodRecipeId)
          E.on     (E.just (m ^. DbMealId) E.==. r ?. DbRecipeMealId)
          E.on     (m ^. DbMealUserId      E.==. u ^. DbUserId)
          E.where_ (m ^. DbMealUserId      E.==. E.val user )
          return (m, r, f)
```

This query is great, it says what it needs, without anything more.  But, because of how SQL works, it gives me back a table with lots of repeated meals, for each outer join that matched.

For instance, a meal with two recipes, each with two foods turns into 4 tuples.

```
(m1, r1, f1)
(m1, r1, f2)
(m1, r2, f3)
(m1, r2, f4)
```

I want to roll these back up into a single `Meal` data type. (simplified here to show structure, other fields of course are stored in the DB).

```
data Meal   = Meal   { recipes :: [Recipe] }
data Recipe = Recipe { foods :: [Food]   }
data Food   = Food   { name :: String }
```

I seem to have to do this merging entirely manually, and it ended up being 2 or so pages of code for this single query.

Ignoring the fact that typeclasses aren't supposed to be used like this, it looks like a lot of instances of a (silly) typeclass `DeserializeDb`:

```
class DeserializeDb a r | a -> r where
  deserializeDb :: a -> r

instance DeserializeDb [(Entity DbMeal, Maybe (Entity DbRecipe))] [Meal] where
  deserializeDb items = let grouped = groupBy (\a b -> entityKey (fst a) == entityKey (fst b)) items
                            joined  = map (\list -> ( (fst . head) list
                                                    ,  mapMaybe snd list
                                                    )) grouped
                        in (map deserializeDb joined)
```

SNIPPED LOTS OF INSTANCES OF VARIOUS COMPLEXITY (code: https://gist.github.com/cschneid/2989057ec4bb9875e2ae)

```
instance DeserializeDb (Entity DbFood) Food where
  deserializeDb (Entity _ val) = Food (dbFoodName val)
```

#### Question:

The only thing I want to expose is the query signature. The rest of this is implementation junk.  Is there a trick to using Persistent that I've not noticed?  Do I have to manually merge joins back into haskell types?

Comment: Your question seems quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686579/haskell-persistent-joins-with-esqueleto, but I don't think you'll like the answers (-:

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing this manually, except it seems to grow in complexity very quickly.  A 3 table join here is 7 lines of query and 80 lines of deserialization.  There must be a better way to handle this.

Comment: I think you should only have deserialization code for the attributes, and obtain a Meal without Recipes, a Recipe without Food in tuples: (Meal,Recipe,Food) then group all the result in one method, it'd be much simpler.

Comment: Sorry? I don't follow.  The issue is that the `(Meal` part of the tuple is repeated, once per unique recipe/food. So most of the `groupBy` junk is fixing that up.  Is there a nicer approach to it?

Comment: I was just thinking that you're conflating deserializing from the DB and grouping results. It may be easier to have basic functions to convert from Entity DbMeal to Meal, etc., and then have a function that perform the grouping without any DB ([(Meal,Recipe,Food)]->[Meal]. You may be able to abstract more and reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JPMoresmau's hinting, I ended up with a much shorter, and I think simpler approach.  It may be slower on large datasets due to `nub`, but on small datasets it returns far faster than I need it to.

I still hate that I have so much manual plumbing to build a tree structure out of the data coming back from the database. I wonder if there's a good way to do this generically?

```
module Grocery.Database.Calendar where

import Grocery.DatabaseSchema
import Grocery.Types.Meal
import Grocery.Types.Recipe
import Grocery.Types.Food
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import qualified Database.Esqueleto      as E
import           Database.Esqueleto      ((^.), (?.))
import Data.Time
import Control.Monad.Trans -- for MonadIO
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Tuple3

getMeals :: (MonadIO m) => Key DbUser -> SqlPersistT m [Meal]
getMeals user =
  fmap deserializeDb $ E.select $
        E.from $ \(m `E.InnerJoin` u `E.LeftOuterJoin` r `E.LeftOuterJoin` f) -> do
          E.on     (r ?. DbRecipeId E.==. f ?. DbFoodRecipeId)
          E.on     (E.just (m ^. DbMealId) E.==. r ?. DbRecipeMealId)
          E.on     (m ^. DbMealUserId      E.==. u ^. DbUserId)
          E.where_ (m ^. DbMealUserId      E.==. E.val user )
          return (m, r, f)

deserializeDb :: [(Entity DbMeal, Maybe (Entity DbRecipe), Maybe (Entity DbFood))] -> [Meal]
deserializeDb results = makeMeals results
  where
    makeMeals :: [(Entity DbMeal, Maybe (Entity DbRecipe), Maybe (Entity DbFood))] -> [Meal]
    makeMeals dupedMeals = map makeMeal (nub $ map fst3 dupedMeals)

    makeMeal :: Entity DbMeal -> Meal
    makeMeal (Entity k m) = let d = dbMealDay m
                                n = dbMealName m
                                r = makeRecipesForMeal k
                            in  Meal Nothing (utctDay d) n r

    makeRecipesForMeal :: Key DbMeal -> [Recipe]
    makeRecipesForMeal mealKey = map makeRecipe $ appropriateRecipes mealKey

    appropriateRecipes :: Key DbMeal -> [Entity DbRecipe]
    appropriateRecipes mealKey = nub $ filter (\(Entity _ v) -> dbRecipeMealId v == mealKey) $ mapMaybe snd3 results

    makeRecipe :: Entity DbRecipe -> Recipe
    makeRecipe (Entity k r) = let n = dbRecipeName r
                                  f = makeFoodForRecipe k
                              in  Recipe Nothing n f

    makeFoodForRecipe :: Key DbRecipe -> [Food]
    makeFoodForRecipe rKey = map makeFood $ appropriateFoods rKey

    appropriateFoods :: Key DbRecipe -> [Entity DbFood]
    appropriateFoods rKey = nub $ filter (\(Entity _ v) -> dbFoodRecipeId v == rKey) $ mapMaybe thd3 results

    makeFood :: Entity DbFood -> Food
    makeFood (Entity _ f) = Food (dbFoodName f)
```